# Selenium suddenly can't find element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So I was building my first webscraper, **scraping** for sports statistics and everything was going great. I had it up and running and collecting data and putting it in a CSV file. Then suddenly overnight it started throwing errors. It went from working to not being able to find elements all without me changing even a letter of the code.

Now when I run it I only get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:
```

The thing is, I know for a fact that that element exists, I can see it on the inspect page and I recopied it to the code.

Before the part that tries to locate this element I have put the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException




    xpath_awayteam = str('.//span[@class="teamNameFirstPart teamNameAwayTextFirstPart smallFont"]')
    timeout = 15
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_awayteam))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)

        print("Page fully loaded")
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")
```

And I get a **Page fully loaded** in the console before the error is raised, so I don't believe the problem lies with the page not loading completely.

I have run into many errors during this process but I'm currently feeling thoroughly beaten and can't figure out what is wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Include the code that produces the exception.  Your expected condition will return the webelement... that's a method, so you're not really using the WebDriverWait correctly there.  It also does not guarantee that the element is visible.

Comment: Sometimes selenium behaves strange on a few websites. Websites know if you are using selenium to access it. I know you can somehow bypass this but I don't know how. But your behavior would still be not normal and human-like. Have you had a look at the robots.txt file if automation is allowed? If no the website might block you. Try running it on different PC if possible to check.